# Core data: How to write "generic" fetch/delete function in swift 3?

Tags: core-data, swift3

I had a function that cleared all objects from given entity, in swift 2:

```
private static func clearTable(tableName : String)
    {
        let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let request = appDel.persistentStoreCoordinator

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: tableName)
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

        do {
            try request.executeRequest(deleteRequest, withContext: context)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }
```

recently i migrated to swift 3 and now it looks like this:

```
static func clearTable(_ tableName : String)
    {
        let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        //let context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: tableName)

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: tableName)
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest(entityName: tableName))

        do {
            try request.execute(deleteRequest, with: context)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }
```

As i understood, now i have to declare `request` and `fetchRequest` like

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SomeEntity> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SomeEntity")
```

The problem is that i don't know the entity beforehand. Is there any workaround or reflexion in swift 3? And i'm new to swift and core data, is this the normal way to fetch or delete objects?

Comment: Your code is a little confusing because of code duplication.  You instantiate the same `NSFetchRequest` 3x.  See my answer for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All result types in Core Data including `NSManagedObject` conform to `NSFetchRequestResult` so use that as type

```
static func clearTable(_ tableName : String)
{
  let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

  let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
  let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: tableName)
  let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request)
  let persistentStoreCoordinator = context.persistentStoreCoordinator!

  do {
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.execute(deleteRequest, with: context)
  } catch let error as NSError {
    debugPrint(error)
  }
}
```

This is the recommended way to delete all items of an entity.
However the deployment target must be ≥ iOS 9 / macOS 10.11.

PS: In Swift 3 I'd declare the function

```
static func clear(table tableName : String) { ...
```

Comment: now i get another error, seems like request.execute() takes 0 arguments

Comment: Dear vadian, I'm trying the same solution but I get error says "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSFetchRequest' in swift 4, is there any import required?

Comment: Yes you have to `import CoreData`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [batch delete example](https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-delete-every-record-of-a-core-data-entity/) for a better way.

I use the CodeDataStack pattern for separation of concern to make the code even more clean.

You can use extension to make your code more dynamic.  Instead of passing the table name, you can simply invoke `model.delete()` or `Model.deleteAll()`.  This is a common pattern used in other web frameworks.

ModelExtension.swift

```
extension NSManagedObject  {

  static func context() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.coreData.context()
  }
  public func delete() {
    managedObjectContext?.delete(self)
  }

  public static func deleteAll() {
    let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: self.fetchRequest())
    do {
      try context().execute(batchDeleteRequest)
    } catch {
      // Error Handling
    }
  }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
// My entity name is `Location`
func test_deleteAll() {
    _ = fixture.buildTestLocation()
    _ = fixture.buildTestLocation()
    coreData.saveContext()

    Location.deleteAll()

    XCTAssertEqual(0, Location.all()?.count)
}
func test_delete() {
    let location = fixture.createTestLocation()
    XCTAssertEqual(1, Location.all()?.count)

    location.delete()
    coreData.saveContext()

    XCTAssertEqual(0, Location.all()?.count)
}
```

Note that `Location.all()` is a custom method.